# How to center elements using freetile.js?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Tried a few css fixes, but it doesn't seem to be happening. Pretty sure the freetile script takes over any of my positioning css anyways.

Ideas anyone?

http://jsfiddle.net/B35Hw/

Edit : text-align:center seems to work for the fiddle, but not my site which is almost exactly the same! : http://elijahhoffman.com/test

My CSS (not going to be helpful outside of context of the Jsfiddle) :

```
#container {position:absolute;top:77px;width:100%;left:0px;}
#container img {height:100px;width:auto;padding:10px;margin:14px;opacity:1;              
                cursor:default; background-color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to your container

In your `#pcontainer img` css, add the following:

```
display: inline-block !important;
position: static !important;
```

This corrects the issue for me. The problem is that each image is set to `position: absolute` which causes `text-align: center` to be ignored.

Comment: wth. I tried this on my actual layout and it wasn't working - but it works on the fiddle! GAH

Comment: @rootsup it's possible some other style is overwriting your text-align: center. Add !important to it to prevent it from being overridden somewhere down the line.

Comment: http://elijahhoffman.com/test - it writes in the middle then everything moves back... so strange @Joel

Comment: @rootsup I have updated the answer to address this on your actual page

Comment: awesome thank you so much!! Why would it work on the fiddle and not my page? Even though it was set to absolute there?

Comment: Turns out there was actually an error in your fiddle. You're using jquery to select the element, but the jquery library wasn't included. You script wasn't running at all so it didn't apply the absolute positioning.

Comment: Ah! Actually looking at it now the freetile script doesn't even function with the position set to static. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

In my case `text-align: center;` does not work, that is why I use `margin` instead:

```
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
}
```